# Travis Build Error

Tags: android, gradle, travis-ci

I am trying to integrate my projec with travis

Here is my travis.yml

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    # The BuildTools version used by your project
    - build-tools-22.0.1
    # The SDK version used to compile your project
    - android-22
    # - extra
    # - tools
    # - platform-tools

    # Specify at least one system image,
    # if you need to run emulator(s) during your tests
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-19
    - sys-img-x86-android-17

before_install: cd MyProject
install: ./gradlew clean build
script: ./gradlew check

notifications:
  email:
    - abc@gmail.com
```

My project structure is like this:

```
Git Repo-> 
- MyProject -> app, gradlew, and all android files are here
- .travis.yml
```

Now I am getting this error

```
> Configuring > 2/2 projectsBuild failed with an exception.
> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Configuring > 2/2 projects> 
> Configuring > 2/2 projectspile'.
> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects> 
> Configuring > 2/2 projects.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0.
> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/appcompat-v7-22.0.0.pom
> Configuring > 2/2 projects/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/appcompat-v7-22.0.0.jar
> Configuring > 2/2 projects2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/appcompat-v7-22.0.0.pom
> Configuring > 2/2 projects2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/appcompat-v7-22.0.0.jar
> Configuring > 2/2 projects2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/appcompat-v7-22.0.0.pom
> Configuring > 2/2 projects2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/appcompat-v7-22.0.0.jar
> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projectsbaJuice:app:unspecified
> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects--stacktrace
> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects--info
> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects--debug
> Configuring > 2/2 projectsore log output.
> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projectsBUILD FAILED
> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projectse: 19.193 secs
> Configuring > 2/2 projects
The command "./gradlew clean build" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

Comment: > Configuring > 2/2 projects> Configuring > 2/2 projectsBUILD FAILED can you build locally using gradlew clean build?

Comment: Thanks alot @AlJacinto for your response. It was building perfectly locally. I have moved everything out of MyProject folder now travis file is parallel to build.gradle and everything is working fine.